# Extremely basic arithmetic simplification

Tags: arithmetic

For the life of me I can't understand my lecturer's working on this.

I have $$\frac{1}{j\omega{L}}$$

Where $\omega=5000$ and $L=0.0001$

He somehow ended up with $$-2j$$

Whereas I simly got $$\frac{1}{2j}or\frac{j^{-1}}{2}$$

Am I not seeing something or do I need to go back to primary school?

Comment: How can you get $2$ at the denominator ? $j^2=-1\iff j=-1/j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0.0001 \times 5000$ is $0.5$, $j$ is the complex unit, which mathematicians don't like in the denominator, so they mulitply top and bottom by it's complex conjugate. Hence;

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{j \omega L} &=& \frac{1}{0.5j} \\
                     &=& \frac{-j}{0.5j(-j)} \\
                     &=& \frac{-j}{0.5(-1)j^{2}} \\
                     &=& \frac{-j}{0.5(-1)^{2}} \\
                     &=& \frac{-j}{0.5} \\
                     &=& -2j.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It would have been nice, of course, if the OP has added the tiny **important** piece of info that $\;j=i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ , but whatever. +1

Comment: Agreed, I guessed it from the fact that I used $j$ instead of $i$ at both sixth form and university. I couldn't see any other way a factor of $-1$ could be incorporated. Many thanks.

Comment: $j=\sqrt{-1}$ is used in electrical engineering, because there $i$ usually denotes current.

Comment: Correct Matt. And thank you Autolatry, that helps a lot.

Comment: @user88720 You're very welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, correct answer is $-2j$ ( You Can get it from multiplying $\frac{2}{j}$ the conjugate of j).